# Compare two lists recursively

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose we have `v1 = list("abcdabcd")` and `v2 = list("caabccab")`, where `a` corresponds to `c`, and `b` corresponds to `d`. Note that the `list()` has separated strings into a list of singletons.

How can we use recursion to find out the longest pair(s), where a pair means, for example, that `cda` and `abc` in this case.

Comment: Are you looking for DNA-like pairing?

Comment: @DavisHerring Right. Do you know some references that can be used?

Comment: Just invert one of them and then look for a “longest common substring” (which is a standard term).  It probably won’t be recursive, though.

Comment: @DavisHerring I have finished the inverting part. Then my idea was to use use recursion to search all appropriate substrings and compare them to get the longest one.

Comment: Is my answer what you're looking for?

Comment: @alec_a Ah.. It isn't. I would like to output to be `cda` `abc`.

Comment: Got it. I edited my answer.

Comment: Does it work how you want it to now?

Comment: @alec_a Thank you for the help. I tried the new one, but it errors out. My code is maybe too complex.

Comment: That's odd, it works perfectly for me. Are you entering very long input that times out?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @alec_a UnboundLocalError: local variable 'max_m1' referenced before assignment. I modified your code a bit so that it "fits" into my code.

Comment: My mistake. I changed some of the variable names but forgot to update their definitions. Should work now (edited).

Comment: the referenced before assignment error would only occur if no matches were found, though. Now it won't occur anyways but still it shouldn't have with these two lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through and detect matches:

```py
v1 = list("abcdabcd")
v2 = list("caabccab")

def longest_match(v1, v2):
    consecutive, max_c, max_m1, max_m2 = [0]*4
    match1, match2 = '', ''
    a, b, c, d = 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'
    for i in range(len(v1)):
        if (v1[i] == a and v2[i] == c) or (v1[i] == c and v2[i] == a) or (v1[i] == b and v2[i] == d) or (v1[i] == d and v2[i] == b):
            consecutive += 1
            match1 += v1[i]
            match2 += v2[i]
        else:
            if consecutive > max_c:
                max_c = consecutive
                max_m1, max_m2 = match1, match2
            consecutive, match1, match2 = 0, '', ''

    match = (max_m1, max_m2)

    return max_c, match

print(longest_match(v1, v2)[1])  # ('cda', 'abc')
```